# sending or storing reports in Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I need your help: Can we set up a daily "list of report" of all reports created per day which will be sent by email or stored on a server?
Do you have any idea how I can do it?
I want to know if there is a standard feature that can do it, if not, what do you suggest as a solution.

Comment: I guess you want a list of reports to be executed ever day, and those reports should be sent on email or to be saved on some server in excel or pdf format.. ? is this what you want

Answer (score 0):

> I had a requirement, where i needed to execute a report on SQL
>   Reporting server and send that report excel to some vendor through
>   email.
>    I did it this way through a custom workflow,
>    for detail blog 
>   [Click Here](http://dotnetjunior.blogspot.com/2016/01/run-existing-ssrs-report-on-sql.html)
>
> I did't write the email part of the code, but you can find here how to
>   send an email through smtp with a file as an attachment.
>   [Click Here](http://dotnetjunior.blogspot.com/2016/01/complete-guide-to-send-email-through.html://)